# Java based text editor is not working while JDK is installed

Tags: java, jvm

I have a Java based Text Editor like Office Word which is used in formal expertises (with .udf extension) and a .exe file which I made with Java SDK. While Java SDK is installed, my Java based text editor is not opening and giving me this Java error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.processAnnotations(java.lang.Class)" because the return value of "com.alee.utils.XmlUtils.getXStream()" is null
    at com.alee.utils.XmlUtils.processAnnotations(XmlUtils.java:141)
    at com.alee.managers.language.LanguageManager.initialize(LanguageManager.java:304)
    at tr.com.havelsan.uyap.system.editor.common.WPAppManager.main(Unknown Source)
```

When I uninstall Java SE Development Kit 19.0.1, text editor opens but my .exe file is not working as expected with following error:

```
A JNI error has occured, please check your installation and try again
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: The first error is a runtime error, possibly a bug in your program. Is the app compatible with Java 19? It may work with an older version (you could try with 8 or 11).

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem today. JAVA_HOME environmental variable might override the JDK you installed. Check your JAVA_HOME environmental variable to verify if it points to the correct version of JDK. For example, my JAVA_HOME variable was pointed to OpenJDK under Android Studio.

I've solved the problem by removing all JDKs using "Add or Remove Programs" feature, removing the JAVA_HOME variable and installing JDK Version 8 Update 391 from the link:

https://www.java.com/en/download/

Answer (score 0):

You need to install 32 bit java

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

if you install java 8 problem is solve. Before you will open uyap programs. after you use open command for file open.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35228060)